# how to implement 'like' and 'in' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have search items for eg `'%ab'`, `'%avcd%'`, `%sr%'`, `'%pple%'` in my PHP variable.
I know LIKE is used in MySQL as:

```
Select * from tblName where fieldname like '%ab'
```

I have a long list of search conditions as mentioned earlier and I know that

```
Select * from tblName where fieldname like in ('%ab','%avcd%','%sr%','%pple%')
```

doesn't work. What is the best way to resolve the problem?

Comment: `...value like ('%ab%') or value like ('%avcd%') or ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * from tblName where fieldname REGEXP 'ab|avcd|sr|pple';
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I didn't knew this pattern. Would be easy to use in future. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[Fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full text indeexing if the table is myisam.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Select * from tblName where fieldname like '%ab' or  fieldname like '%ab' or  fieldname like %sr%' or  fieldname like '%pple%'